# How to avoid Relationship "My father is my son"

Tags: spring

Once again I must to ask you to help me with my project.

My Relation Class :

```
private GT_Member mother;

private GT_Member father;

private GT_Family ownerF;

private List<GT_Member> children;
```

How can I implemented in  Spring application the verification parentage ?? I would like to forbid set father or grandfather of one person as his son.

In client lourd is the simple situation, I do filtrage the list.  But how do it in database ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `addChild` method and check the hierarchy recursively upwards to ensure that the child isn't part of their own ancestry.

Like this:

```
public class GT_Member {

    private final GT_Member mother;

    private final GT_Member father;

    private final List<GT_Member> children;

    public GT_Member(final GT_Member mother, final GT_Member father) {
        this.mother = mother;
        this.father = father;
        this.children = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /**
     * Add a child to this member.
     * @param child
     */
    public void addChild(GT_Member child) {
        if (child == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null children not allowed");
        }
        if (child.equals(this)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't add self as a child");
        }
        if (isAncestor(child)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't add an ancestor as a child");
        }
        children.add(child);
    }

    /**
     * Check if a member is an ancestor to this member.
     * @param member
     * @return True if the member is an ancestor, false otherwise
     */
    private boolean isAncestor(final GT_Member member) {
        // Check if the member is the mother or father
        return member.equals(mother) || member.equals(father)
                // Check if the member is an ancestor on the mother's side
                || (mother != null && mother.isAncestor(member))
                // Check if the member is an ancestor on the father's side
                || (father != null && father.isAncestor(member));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the check in two levels
1. Business logic validation in the application code. 
2. Database Triggers to ensure such non-conforming relations is not created / updated.

Comment: I prefere do it in business logic because I must check also that my cousin  is not my son, or my wife is not my daughter.. etc.etc...